# Como posso inserir dados em duas tabelas diferentes?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Eu criei uma função para inserir informações para duas tabelas diferentes, mas está apresentando um erro:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'insert into client(name, reg, adress, phone) values('mary',2147483647,'a' at line 2

Minha função é:

```
function newUser($connect, $name, $reg, $address, $phone, $email, $pass){
    $query = "insert into user(email, password) values('{$email}','{$pass}'); 
              insert into client(name, reg, address, phone) values('{$name}','{$reg}','{$address}','{$phone}')";
    return mysqli_query($connect, $query);
}
```

Quando testo a consulta direto no banco, funciona. :(

Comment: **Rafael**, tal como o nome sugere (StackOverflow **em português**), o idioma oficial usado aqui é o português. Assim sendo, você poderia por favor traduzir sua pergunta? Caso prefira, você também pode fazer essa mesma pergunta no [site em inglês do StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Isso tá parecendo um [problema de injeção de sql](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3864/como-prevenir-inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-c%C3%B3digo-sql-no-meu-c%C3%B3digo-php). O conteúdo da sua variável `$address` parece estar interferindo na interpretação da consulta. Por certo ponto de vista, ainda bem que não funcionou: você não vai querer essa vulnerabilidade no seu sistema. Dá merda.

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza O problema de sintaxe não é referente a variável `$address`. Pode até ser que esteja com esse problema também. Mas neste caso, se você fizer mais de uma query com a função `mysqli_query` esse problema irá ocorrer também! Essa pergunta não deveria ser fechada.

Comment: @AndreiCoelho Entendi. Não conheço de php, vou retratar a sinalização. Obrigado. Achei que pudesse ser a questão da injeção porque na mensagem a instrução aparece truncada.

Comment: Obrigado, Diego. Eu acabei nao reparando que era o em português. Já vi que traduziu e desculpe por isto.

Answer (score 0):

Use o **[multi_query](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.multi-query.php)** para fazer mais de uma query ao mesmo tempo. Assim:

```
function newUser($connect, $name, $reg, $address, $phone, $email, $pass){
    $query = "insert into user(email, password) values('{$email}','{$pass}'); 
              insert into client(name, reg, address, phone) values('{$name}','{$reg}','{$address}','{$phone}')";

    return mysqli_multi_query($connect, $query); // aqui será realizado as duas querys
}
```

Esse erro sintaxe ocorre justamente porque você está tentando realizar mais de uma query usando a função `mysqli_query`.

Comment: Obrigado, Andrei! Eu não sabia desta funcionalidade. Enfim, o começo é assim mesmo :)

Comment: @RafaelFigueiredo tranquilo! Boa sorte!